# Euclidean Geometry versus Analytic Geometry versus Affine Geometry?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, affine-geometry

What are the relationships (connections) among:

- Euclidean (or Plane) geometry
- Analytic geometry
- Affine geometry

How do these things relate?

I know that this is a very general question, so I'm looking for a simple overview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Felix Klein defined geometry to be the study of invariants of group actions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program)

Euclidean geometry looks at things unchanged by [Euclidean transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation), i.e. rigid transformations, i.e. rotations, translations (and sometimes reflections).

Affine geometry looks at things unchanged by [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). This usually means non-singular linear transformations, i.e. $\det M \neq 0$. An important subset, equi-affine geometry, studies linear transformations which preserve area, i.e. $\det M = 1$.

Projective geometry does the same with [projective transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography).

Analytic geometry doesn't really fit in to this. For me, "analytic geometry" just means "using coordinates". All of Euclidean, affine and projective geometry can be done using coordinates.

Maybe I misunderstand "analytic geometry".

Comment: +1 yes, "analytic geometry" and "synthetic geometry" describe two approaches to studying geometry, not really different "types" of geometries. It doesn't really belong in the same basket as the others.  Actually one can show that there is an equivalence between defining Pappian geometries synthetically and geometries using coordinates from fields analytically.

Comment: I agree, to me "Analytic geometry = Euclidean geometry (+) coordinates". Thanks for the answer

Comment: I have never heard of affine transformations being restricted to area-preserving transformations.

Comment: @rschwieb Can you add some reference concerning the equivalence you mentioned?

Comment: @EricWofsey I come from a background of *differential* geometry, and there "Affine" almost always means "equi-affine", aka "uni-modular". Terms like "affine arc-length", "affine normal", "affine curvature", "affine evolute" all refer to *equi-affine*. I agree that it's rather misleading. As Guggenheimer says "An affine transformation can always be broken up into a special volume-conserving affine transformation followed by a homothety. This approach is better suited for differential geometry..."

I've fixed my post to make the distinction.

Comment: @PtF I don’t know if I remember one precisely, but I think Hartshorne might cover it in his geometry books.

Comment: Now, to answer the question, you have to explain the relationships among those groups of transformations

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean Geometry is geometry studied by Euclid that is based off of shapes with no values.  Analytical Geometry is geometry on planes with values.  So, the difference is mainly that Euclidean doesn't use specific values